# Ajax is not working with dimmer view

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am developing web based application in that I want to use dimmer view to add master information and as per this parent form needs to be refreshed.
In that dimmer view is working correctly but when I am trying to save values of child form in database using ajax but it doesn't work. If I removed ajax part it saves but it goes to the next page and I don't want this.

Here is my ajax code

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#enter1').click(function(e) 
        {
            alert("In Ajax..");
            e.preventDefault();

            var ajaxdata = $("#v1").val();
            var ajaxdata1 = $("#v2").val();
            var ajaxdata2 = $("#v3").val();
            var ajaxdata3 = $("#v4").val();
            var ajaxdata4 = $("#v5").val();
            var ajaxdata5 = $("#v6").val();
            var ajaxdata6 = $("#v7").val();
            var ajaxdata7 = $("#v8").val();
            var ajaxdata8 = $("#v9").val();
            var ajaxdata9 = $("#v10").val();
            var ajaxdata10 = $("#v11").val();

        var value ='v1='+ ajaxdata +'&v2='+ ajaxdata1 +'&v3='+ ajaxdata2 +'&v4='+ ajaxdata3 +'&v5='+ ajaxdata4 +'&v6='+ ajaxdata5 +'&v7='+ ajaxdata6 +'&v8='+ ajaxdata7 +'&v9='+ ajaxdata8 +'&v10='+ ajaxdata9 +'&v11='+ ajaxdata10 ;

        alert(value);

        $.ajax({

            type:"get",  
            url: "MasterServlet", 
            data: value, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                 $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                 $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
             }

         });

         return false;
        });
   }); 

</script>
```

And my jsp button

```
<input type="button" id="enter1" name="enter1" value="Submit">
```

Can any one suggest me how to save values of dimmer view form using ajax?

Comment: No, I have not get any error. Can you please tell me how to check network panel for ajax call?

Comment: try `$.ajax({

            type:"get",  
            url: "MasterServlet?"+value, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                 $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                 $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
             }

         });

         return false;
        });` i believe you are messing with url formation

Comment: @Arvind I could not found Net/Netwokk tab in my IE 8 and I have put alert in success. I think ajax doesn't receive any call because atleast "In Ajax" message needs to displayed

Comment: @pankajparkar  i tried with your code but it doesn't work

Comment: @PriyankaPawar  Are you sure you are hitting correct `MasterServlet` action? What would be desired path of server side method?

Comment: @pankajparkar yes, when I remove my ajax part it works fine

Comment: @PriyankaPawar, try running server in debug mode and put a breakpoint at servlet doGet() method

Comment: @PriyankaPawar  Oh cool, that means you are using form, could you please tell me `action` attribute which you had in form element of your html?

Comment: @Arvind I have done with this now what should I do?

Comment: @PriyankaPawar, now click the button and see whether the servlet get the call

Comment: @pankajparkar < form name="f1" action="MasterServlet" method="get">

Comment: It shows suspended entry into doGet in MasterServlet

Comment: use `type: 'GET'` instead of `type: 'get'` & add `dataType: 'json',` have you tried the same code on chrome? Does it work?

Comment: Usually I am using internal web browser of tomcat but yes I have tried on IE and chrome. And this changes also not working

Comment: @PriyankaPawar  does `alert("In Ajax..");` is firing.?

Comment: No. Ajax doesn't received any call